# How do I define and register a shortcode function in a namespaced functions.php file?

Tags: shortcode, codex, namespace

I wrote a function in my theme's `functions.php` and am attempting to register it with `add_shortcode()` as [shown](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) in the Codex:

```php
<?php
/**
 * theme's functions.php
 */

namespace MyNamespace;

//[foobar]
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

However this does not work and a post containing `[foobar]` simply renders "[foobar]" as text instead of being replaced by the handler function's return value.

My guess is it has something to do with my `functions.php` being namespaced. Does something special need to be done to reference namespaced Callables in `add_shortcode`?

Answer (score 1):

[Thanks to Stanislav Khromov](https://snippets.khromov.se/using-add_shortcode-with-namespaces-in-wordpress/) (also active [on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/40449)!), I learned any Callable referenced in `add_shortcode()` must be fully qualified, even if it is defined in the same file you're referencing it.

```php
<?php
/**
 * theme's functions.php
 */

namespace MyNamespace;

//[foobar]
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', '\MyNamespace\foobar_func' );
```

You [may omit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php) the leading backslash, if you prefer: `add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'MyNamespace\foobar_func' );`

Comment: You can make it dynamic if in the future the namespace will change you will not have to manually edit the add_shortcode function, using `__NAMESPACE__` magic constant.